# List comprehension in Haskell

Tags: haskell, list-comprehension

I've been using the following code to get all combinations of a pre-determined amount of numbers:

```
getList x = [ [a,b,c] | a <- [1..x], b <- [1..x], c <- [1..x]]
```

This was fine to begin with, but I'm looking to expand the program to handle very large lists, and I keep thinking there must be a better way to do this. How would I create a function that takes the same parameter x as here, and also another parameter for how many items the sublists have. For four items I would go and modify the code:

```
getList x = [ [a,b,c,d] | a <- [1..x], b <- [1..x], c <- [1..x], d <- [1..x]]
```

It doesn't need to be a list comprehension. Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I believe what you want would be the `replicateM` function in `Control.Monad`.

The list monad is based on "trying all possible combinations", and plain `replicate` creates a list by repeating an item some number of times. So the result of `replicateM` is, given some list of possible values, a list of all possible ways to select an item from that list some number of times.

For example:

```
> replicateM 2 [0, 1]
[[0,0],[0,1],[1,0],[1,1]]
> replicateM 3 [0, 1]
[[0,0,0],[0,0,1],[0,1,0],[0,1,1],[1,0,0],[1,0,1],[1,1,0],[1,1,1]]
```

So to extend your function to arbitrary repetitions, you'd use something like:

```
getListN n x = replicateM n [1..x]
```

...where your original `getList` would be equivalent to `getListN 3`.

Comment: Thanks, that function covers everything I wanted to get done there.

Comment: +1 Favorited. I'll definitely have to decompose/desugar this for myself and see the inner workings of this monadic magic.

Comment: @Dan: If it helps, I can say that the end result is pretty much the same as what the list comprehension in the question does, and that most of the magic is happening in the `sequence` function.

Answer (score 3):

In case, anyone likes a non-Monadic-solution to understand to inner workings (although, the soliution via `replicateM` is great!):

```
getListN n = foldl (\ass bs -> [ b:as | b <- bs, as <- ass]) [[]] . replicate n
```

Essentially, this implementation via `foldl` works exactly in the same way as the `replacatM`-solution does.

Comment: I think `sequence` actually uses a right fold, not left. Otherwise, yes, this is equivalent to `replicateM`'s implementation as `sequence . replicate n`.

Comment: @camccann - you're right! `sequence ms = foldr ...` - thanks for the hint